# calculating server throughput for selenium python automation test?

Tags: python, selenium

I have a selenium python automation test and I want to calculate the number of requests per second server can handle.
The logic that I am using is

> 1 sample, 1 thread\user, 1 second delay + (assume for) a 2 second response time to load the page = 3 seconds Total delay between requests = Thread will execute 20 times per 1 minute = 0.33 Hits/s

But i am not sure whether this is correct or not. How do you calculate throughput for a selenium automation test ?

Is this even possible ?

Comment: there are other tools that are better suited for this.  Google "load testing web site"

Comment: @pcalkins hey thanks i understand, but I just want formula for calculating throughput. As I want to add it in the test report

Answer (score 2):

You should choose the right tool for the job. Selenium is not a load testing tool. There are great load testing tools out there like [JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/), [Gatling](https://github.com/gatling/gatling), [Ddosify](https://github.com/ddosify/ddosify), etc. I'll suggest ddosify since I'm the co-author and I think it is the easiest one to use.

First, you need to do some experiments. For example, start with sending 10 requests per second by using [linear load type](https://github.com/ddosify/ddosify#linear). Linear load type equally distributes total requests count (`-n` flag) to duration (`-d` flag).

```
ddosify -t target.com -n 100 -d 10 -l linear
```

If you see no failed request that means the target system can handle 10 RPS. Increase the total requests count until you see failed runs in the output.

Comment: hey , i really appreciate your answer. I will definately read about Ddosify and will  use it future for sure. As of now the requirement I have needs to be solved using selenium. Thanks for your inputs.